Frag Y coord goes from -600 to 0 after adding frame buffer?
After adding a frame buffer and then drawing to it, the default frame buffers frag coordinate y becomes -600 at the bottom and the top is 0, rather than bottom being 0 and top being 600.
I've messed around with the window size, the frame buffer size, and the viewport. But nothing has changed the frag coordinate from being negative.
The moment I draw to the frame buffer, the frag coordinate changes.
To test the frag coord, I check if the y coord is over -300, and brighten the colour if so. Since it goes to -600, half the screen lights up.
Here's the code to reproduce the error, the shaders are included in the same page for simplicity:
#include <glad/glad.h> 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

// vertex shader
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";

// fragment shader
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"vec4 light = vec4(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"if (gl_FragCoord.y > -300)\n"
"{\n"
"light = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n"
"FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f) * light;\n"
"}\n\0";

const int Width = 800;
const int Height = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(Width, Height, "Test", 
      NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // vertex shader
    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    unsigned int fragmentShader = 
    glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // link shaders
    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);


    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    float square[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(square), square, 
      GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * 
      sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    float vertices[] = {
        // pos      // tex
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    unsigned int FBO;
    unsigned int quadVAO;
    unsigned int texture;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, 
      GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * 
      sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // load framebuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, Width, Height, 0, 
      GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 
      GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, 
      GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
      GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    // renderbufferobject
    unsigned int RBO;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &RBO);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, RBO);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 
      Width, Height);

    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == 
      GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cout << "FBO connected" << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect to FBO" << 
        glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) << "\n";
    }


    // render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // frame buffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);
        glClearColor(0.11f, 0.16f, 0.32f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        
        // draw square
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        // not drawing here stops the issue
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        // back to default frame buffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0.11f, 0.16f, 0.32f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // draw square
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


IIRC the glViewport() state is part of the FBO and affects gl_FragCoord; does calling glViewport() with the framebuffer size after binding the FBO change anything?

Thanks for showing me glfwGetFramebufferSize(), sadly glviewport() before or after any of the FBO binds is making no difference.

One strange thing I have found, after drawing to the FBO if I bind another FBO and then call 'glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` before going back to the default FBO, the frag y coordinate goes back to normal.

I found out it's a driver bug, I ran it on a different pc and there was no change in frag coordinates.
